# How to load container and get data in google tag manager v5 in android

Tags: android, google-tag-manager

How to get data from google tag mager v5 container. I already add my container GTM-XXXXX.json to assets/container. I need to know how load this container and get data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you've setup Firebase as [documented](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5/), and added Google Tag Manager to your build.gradle, Google Tag Manager v5 automatically loads the container you've placed in assets/containers (Note the s in containers). You then use Firebase Analytics logEvent calls, which cause Tag Manager to evaluate triggers.

v5 doesn't support retrieving settings from a container. [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/) provides that functionality.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for Firebase Remote Config functionality.